# if(Serial.available()>0) VS while(Serial.available()>0)

Tags: serial, shift-register

What's the low level difference between `if(Serial.available() > 0)` and `while(Serial.available() > 0)`? On what conditions would you choose one over the other?

I was testing my codes on 4 daisy chained 74HC595 shift registers controlling multiple LEDs. The code takes in a number from the serial monitor and displays it out in binary via the LEDs. Here is the code below that worked:

```
#define latchPin 8  //ST_CP pin of 74HC595
#define clockPin 9  //SH_CP pin of 74HC595
#define dataPin 7   //DS pin of 74HC595

//number of 74HC595 in daisy chain
#define numOfDaisyChainReg 4

byte registerVal[numOfDaisyChainReg];

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    
    uint32_t num = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print(num, DEC);
    Serial.print(" : ");
    Serial.println(num, BIN);

    //breaks the recieved int into 4 unsigned bytes
    //and assigns the byte value into the "registerVal" array
    for (uint8_t a = 0; a < numOfDaisyChainReg; a++) {
      registerVal[a] = (num >> (numOfDaisyChainReg - (a + 1)) * 8) & 0xFF;
      Serial.print("registerVal["); Serial.print(a); Serial.print("] = ");
      Serial.println(registerVal[a], BIN);
    }

    //writes the 4 bytes into the shift register
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < numOfDaisyChainReg; x++) {
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, registerVal[x]);
    }
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    
  }
    
}
```

Originally, I had `if(Serial.available() > 0)` and that didn't work as no LEDs lit up despite everything else in the code working as it was expected. Switching to `while(Serial.available() > 0)` solved that problem. Anyone have any idea why that's the case?

Comment: Turn up the warning level in `File/Preferences` with regard to `while(Serial.available)` without `()` , as in `.available()`.

Comment: `despite everything else in the code working as it was expected` ... that may not be true

Comment: think of a sink full of dirty dishes .... `if (dirtyDish.available > 0) {washDishOrNot()}` , lets you go to sink, maybe wash a dish or a few, and go play ...... `while (dirtyDish.available > 0) {washDishOrNot()}` would have you stuck at the sink until there were no dirty dishes, or until you used an emergency escape

Comment: I'm hoping that it's just a typo, since it's not in the main listing, and answered the part I could.  And also that it doesn't just come down to not reading about  [`while`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/while/) and [`if`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/if/).

Comment: @timemage opps it was a typo. The code section had it as 'Serial.available()' but forgot to put the '()' outside of that. My bad. I'll fix it.

Comment: @jsotola I had a feeling it'd be something like that. Curious to what ends/breaks that if(Serial.available() > 0) statement. Based on the logic of the code, I should finish the for loop inside before the if serial statement ends. By finishing the for loop, the shift register should be able to output to the LEDs.

Comment: the `if` statement checks availability of data ... you can assemble the received bytes in a buffer, if you want, or do nothing at all ... you would check each byte for end-of-data value ... normally a newline `'\n'` ... when end-of-data is received, you process the buffer .... the thing is, you could do other tasks when receiving serial data

Comment: @jsotola Let's say if I wanted to use `if(Serial.available() > )` instead of `while' so the arduino does other tasks while receiving the int number I put in. What lines of code would I need to add to make it work like it was before?

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: @jsotola. Thanks! It was an interesting read. I'll implement it into my code for testing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out why `while(Serial.available()>0)` and `if(Serial.available() > 0)` would or would NOT work in terms of my shift register code. It has to do with the serial monitor **line feed and carriage return setting**! If it isn't set to no line ending, it will either not register the input number or reset it back to zero right after the input is read. Learned to always check the line return option in the serial monitor! With this solved, the original question is nothing more than a general `if` vs `while` statement; which I already know the answer.

**Thanks to everyone who contributed to this question!** It did help me understand a lot more about `Serial.available()` in general. @jsotola gave a really good [article](http://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino). Combined with this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qCjCRBLv_VM), it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations of the Arduino core have features that need `loop()` to exit regularly.  Although it's not often used, the [`serialEvent()` is an example](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/serialevent/) of one such thing, at least in the [AVR Arduino core](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.3/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L47).

The ESP8266 Arduino core appears to do some [task scheduling](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp#L198) when `loop()` exits, among other things.

For your particular use case, it may make no difference at all, probably doesn't.  It *may* not even generate different code once compiled.  If you were doing something where you could not afford to exit `loop()`, run other stuff and re-enter `loop()` to run your code for a second pass, then there might be a performance reason to use your own while loop inside `loop()`.  In your code as it currently is, the eventual blocking on `Serial` writes will end up limiting the execution to the same speed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. So you're saying there is a chance `loop()` function exiting/ending and that might break the code if using the `if(Serial.available())`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, and it seems like I should if the answer to it were anything other than "no, that wasn't what I was saying."  Since replacing the `while` in your code with an `if` results in `loop()` exiting more frequently, since that is the difference, and you asked "On what conditions would you choose one over the other?", that is what I addressed.  It's the best interpretation of your question that I could come up with.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Seems to me that the if statements doesn't behave as I'd expect it to when it's paired with the Serial.available(). It might exit pre-maturely.